# Cannot run sudo from Hudson job, but sudo works directly on the system

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We have a linux system that we do not have full control of.  Basically we cannot modify sudoers file there (it is on a remote, read only file system).

Our "solution" for hudson user to have sudo privileges was to add this user to sudo group in /etc/group file.  With this approach I can execute sudo as hudson user once I ssh to the machine.  However, when I try to execute sudo from a Hudson job on this system, I get the following error:

```
+ id
uid=60000(hudson) gid=60000(hudson) groups=60000(hudson),31(sudo)
+ cat passfile
+ sudo -S -v
Sorry, user hudson may not run sudo on sc11136681.
+ cat passfile
+ sudo -S ls /root
hudson is not allowed to run sudo on sc11136681.  This incident will be reported.
```

The above is trying to execute:

```
cat passfile | sudo -S -v
cat passfile | sudo -S ls /root
```

Why does it work when I ssh to the machine directly but does not when Hudson uses ssh?  Is there a way to make sudo work in Hudson job without adding hudson user to the sudoers file?

**Edit**: here is output when executing sudo commands after I ssh to the system as hudson user:

```
[hudson@sc11136681 ~]$ cat passfile | sudo -S -v
[sudo] password for hudson: [hudson@sc11136681 ~]$
[hudson@sc11136681 ~]$
[hudson@sc11136681 ~]$ cat passfile | sudo -S ls /root
anaconda-ks.cfg  install.log.syslog               jaytest
install.log      iscsi_pool_protocol_fields_file  subnets
```

Comment: what is the line for hudson in `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: Cannot view the file: permission denied.  I'm quite sure hudson user is not in the sudoers file.

Comment: you can do `visudo` to see the file and which linux are you using?

Comment: Cannot view file with visudo, error: $ visudo
visudo: /usr/local/packages/sudo_remote/1.6.7p5/etc/sudoers: Read-only file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem that worked for us was to install local sudo on the system.  Command used:

> sudo yum reinstall sudo

Once installed, had to make sure the right sudo was used:

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

The above can be added to slave configuration so it works for all jobs on that slave.